# If value in table over max value, make value equal max value

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres table, if I have a column with some kind of check (for example `hp`, and `CHECK (hp < 100)`), and I give the DB HP with value 101, then it will error out.

How do I instead insure that the DB will just insert the max value, 100, any time `hp` is over the max value?

EDIT: I am using Postgres v. 9.3.2, not sure if that matters

Comment: I don't think you can do it without the help of trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a before trigger to do what you want:

```
new.value = least(100,new.value);
```

This will ensure that any row inserted will have `new.value <= 100` *unless* an additional before trigger kicks in and changes the value after that. So adding the extra `check()` constraint is also useful.

---

Old answer for reference (I understood you wanted the maximum value to increment as new invalid rows were inserted):

You need a trigger, and probably a sequence to do this.

If having an occasional hole is not an option, you need to actually lock the table, or obtain an advisory lock tied to the table and the current max value:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

If it is, a sequence can be used to avoid the thorny issue of needing to obtain that lock. You'd run something like:

```
if not exists (select 1 from tbl where value > new.value) then
  new.value := nextval('tbl_max_value_seq');
end if;
```

Comment: The ceiling seems to be fixed so what's the sequence for?

Comment: @muistooshort: Actually, as I understand OP's question, the ceiling increments by one each time a new value in excess of the max is supposed to get inserted. Else a simple check, which OP actually mentions, would be just fine (and just right). :-(

Comment: "How do I instead insure that the DB will just insert the max value, 100, any time hp is over the max value?" so a `new.value := least(new.value, 100)` seems to be called for.

Comment: @Denis Sorry if I was being confusing. The ceiling is fixed.

Comment: Ah, OK. I edited the answer accordingly. (Basically: +1 @muistooshort with a comment on enforcing the check.)